# Ugly borders in OS X

Tags: macos, windows

[image: pic]

I recently switched to OS X from linux. And the thing that annoys me really much is ugly white spaces at the right and the bottom of the screen. You can see it at the picture attached. And I can't resize the window.

Does anyone have the same problem as me? I have MBP 13" 2011. Is there a way to delete these spaces out of the box or should I install some third-party software?

link to pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2Rdj.png

Comment: You said, "_You can see it at the picture attached_", well there's no picture attached.

Comment: whoops. i gave the link

Comment: The right border is because the window isn't stretched the full width. The bottom border will always be there.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, that's the space that indicates that the dock is on that side. BUT, what you can do is move the dock to the left or right if really bothers you that much. You are limited to space from top to bottom, but not left to right, so you can override that little space on the sides but not at the bottom. :)

If you don't like it in the sides, you can move it to the sides, resize your window to 100% height, then move the dock back to bottom. You will see the space is gone.

Alternative: Go fullscreen mode <kbd>cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: The second part(move dock to the left and back to the bottom) didn't work for me. Fullscreen is not for me because I use hotkeys to jump between spaces. I think I'll try some window manager. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: After you have moved the dock, you need to resize the window to 100%, it wont resize itself. And I just tried it twice, it works. But okay..

Comment: FWIW I think that the "border" on the bottom is there as a subtle reminder for the user (to toggle Dock visibility). You can make the window taller than 100% height — drag the window past the bottom of screen, and then heighten from top — if it's really bothering you.